# What is the exact meaning or purpose of Kawthar? (On Surah Al-Kawthar)

Tags: tafseer, terminology, surat-al-kawthar

According to the initial verse of [Surah Al-Kawthar](https://quran.com/108):

> إِنَّا أَعْطَيْنَاكَ الْكَوْثَرَ /  Indeed, We have granted you, [O
>   Muhammad], al-Kawthar.

I have heard that the meaning of Kawthar (in the mentioned verse) is “plenty of weal (Al-Khair Al-Kathir) or (Abundant good) ”
but I was wondering what its precise meaning or purpose is in that verse? (Actually, what kind of weal?)

Comment: I remember reading that this verse was sent when Muhammad (ﷺ) was at the lowest points in his life, with a low amount of followers and a lot of enemies who planned to kill him. This verse was a prophecy as well as a promise to Muhammad (ﷺ), that he will be given abundant good. I will search more to understand what is meant by "abundant good".

Comment: @Hakim,nice answer, but i'd be thankful if you render some sources for your claim. God bless you.

Comment: See these [notes](http://www.scribd.com/fullscreen/78300190?access_key=key-1ygr0bjh45hh9qat8mng&allow_share=false&escape=false&show_recommendations=false&view_mode=scroll) by Nouman Ali Khan. You may find them useful.

Comment: i red your link somewhat.it was relatively a detailed and long text. God bless you.

Comment: Glad I could help, if you found there all what you needed you may write an answer to your question and accept it! ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Kawthar means Kasir-al-khair (plenty of weal or abundant good).

**It consists of some other meanings such as pool or river of Kawthar, intercession (Shifa'a), wisdom (Hikmah), science (Elm), plenty of descendant, and plenty of progeny (Zoriah) which could be related to Hazrat Fatimah (s.a.) according to the view of Shia, as the progeny(Zorriah) of the Prophet (SAWW).**

---

For further info. regarding Kawthar, you can refer to the site below (Source).

(Note: this site is in Arabic and Urdu)

---

**Source**:

[http://islamquest.net (Arabic)](http://islamquest.net/ar/archive/question/fa1068) and [Urdu](http://islamquest.net/ur/archive/question/fa1068)

Comment: I didn't know it was Kasir-al-khair, but until now I just used to believe that Kauthar is just the river in paradise specially for Prophet Muhammad(pbuh).

Comment: Yeah Dear ServantofWiser, there could be several meanings for it (at least from Shia's viewpoint), and I reckon According to Shia "Haztat-Fatimah" would be as a main probable item.. God Bless You for searching in different ..

Answer (score 0):

The Qur'an verse says about a **pool in Mahshar** (flatten world to a ground), when all humanity will be resurrected and standing in Mahshar after world's end, a sun will be placed above every human's head, that heat will blow human's brain. At that time, Believers of Allah in time of Each prophet will be given a pool of Water to reduce the heat, and the **name of the pool will be given to Prophet Muhammad (pbuh) is Kawsar (كوثر)**.

> --Al-Bhuhari 4964,4965,6581,7517

Answer (score -1):

From the Arabic 3 letter verbal origin **ك ث ر (plentiful)**.

Meanings:

1: Abundance.
2: River/pool in paradise.
3: A sweet drink.
4: A generous person.

**Source:**

- [www.maajim.com](http://www.maajim.com/dictionary/%D9%83%D9%88%D8%AB%D8%B1)

Comment: Unfortunately from 5 meanings in your link among two really refer to Kawthar which is quoted in the Qur'an you only quoted 4 without quoting the 2nd meaning which refers to the Verse/Surah which means the plentiful good (or ease) in this life and the hereafter!